# Terraform error when make's terraform apply command

Tags: ansible, terraform

When I do `terraform plan -var-file=../variables.tfvars`
pass all good

But then I run `terraform apply -var-file=../variables.tfvars`

give me this error and I don't know how to solve this because the directory's path is correct.

> Error: Error applying plan:
>   1 error(s) occurred:
>   * aws_instance.mongodb_server: 1 error(s) occurred:
>   * Error running command 'sleep 60 && export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False && echo "[mongodb]
>   54.193.20.170" > /tmp/inventory.ws && ansible-playbook -i /tmp/inventory.ws -e "mongodb_password=blahblah" -e "mongodb_user=admin" -u ec2-user -b --private-key=../BASE/files/joujou.pem ../DATABASE/files/ansible-mongodb-standalone/mongodb.yml': exit status 127. Output: /bin/sh: 2: ansible-playbook: not found

The code is like:

```
resource "aws_instance" "mongodb_server" {

    instance_type = "${lookup(var.mongodb_instance_type_control, 
    var.target_env)}"
    vpc_security_group_ids = 
    ["${aws_security_group.default_internal.id}"]
    ami = "${lookup(var.amazon_ami_by_location, var.aws_region)}"
    key_name = "${var.key_name}"
    subnet_id = "${data.aws_subnet.subnet_a.id}"

    tags {
        Name = "tf-mongodb-${lookup(var.environment, var.target_env)}"
    }

    associate_public_ip_address = true

    provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 60 && export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False && echo \"[mongodb]\n${aws_instance.mongodb_server.public_ip}\" > /tmp/inventory.ws && ansible-playbook -i /tmp/inventory.ws -e \"mongodb_password=${var.mongodb_default_password}\" -e \"mongodb_user=${var.mongodb_default_username}\" -u ec2-user -b --private-key=../BASE/files/joujou.pem ../DATABASE/files/ansible-mongodb-standalone/mongodb.yml"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Output: /bin/sh: 2: ansible-playbook: not found

This is your actual error. Terraform plan does not capture this error as local-exec commands are not evaluated by terraform plan.

Do you have ansible installed on the machine where you are trying to run the above terraform? And if installed, is it on the path.

Try [installing ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_installation.html) if its not installed already. If ansible is already installed, do a `echo $PATH` in your local-exec command and confirm if ansible is present in the given path.